# Discord.js forward all messages to server owner

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to do this flow and how can I do it with Discord.js

**USER** ➜ (user message bot) ➜ **BOT** ➜ (forward message of user) ➜ **SPECIFIC USER**

*Example:*
**John** ➜ 'message: Hello' ➜ **BOT** ➜ (John: Hello) ➜ **Server Owner**

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Could you please add some information about what you have tried after reading the discord.js docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    if (message.channel.type !== "dm") return false;

    const User = await message.client.users.cache.get("<User ID>");
    if (!User) return false;
    User.send(`${message.author.tag}: \n ${message.content}`, {split: true}).catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

This will detect all DMs sent to the bot and send them to you.

Comment: This will make the bot to spam the user you sent the message to.

Comment: where can i get <User ID> is it Mashwishi#5108 or the <@221838936866029568>

Comment: It's 221838936866029568